# C#-like properties in native C++?

Tags: c++

In [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) / [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) you can do something like this:

```
someThing.text = "blah";
String blah = someThing.text;
```

However, the above code does not actually interact with the someThing's text String directly, it uses a get and set property. Similarly, read-only properties can be used.

Is there a way to do something similar in native [C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++)? (not C++ .NET)

Comment: I'm NOT an expert, but why not let `someThing.text` be a public member if you're going to treat it like one anyway?

Comment: Exposing members (even as read only) via getter and setters is bad OO. You are exposing the internal representation of your object to the world. Even if this is slightly protected by using methods (hidden behind syntactic sugar of properties) it provides a public API that must be maintained. The question is why are you trying to expose your members? Object should be using the internal representation to perform tasks not exposing it for other people to perform tasks. Rather than exposing the implementation expose an action method that uses the representation.

Comment: I question the utility of paying an efficiency cost for obscuring the code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does C++11 have C#-style properties?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In .NET properties are syntactic sugar for the real `get` and `set` functions which are emitted behind the scenes (in fact they are more than syntactic sugar because properties are emitted in the resulting IL and could be used with Reflection). So in C++ you would need to explicitly write those functions as there's no such notion as property.

Comment: But how does it know if the user wants to get or set? Does operator overloading need to be used?

Comment: When it is on the left hand-side of the assignment operator (`=`) you are setting, when it is on the right you are getting and the compiler is smart enough to figure this out.

Comment: Writing two functions on that will return a reference, and one that will return a const reference is very useful, the compiler will figure out when to call which.  But this will allow to make these calls in any places (inside const functions).

Comment: -1 as demonstrated by [Moo-Juice's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4225302/464581) the "in C++ you would need to explicitly write those functions as there's no such notion as property" is trivially, directly wrong. And there are also other ways to properties in C++, including source code preprocessing. The technical possibility of portable properties in C++ does not, however, mean that it's a good idea to do it... :-)

Answer (score 53):

**WARNING: This is a tongue-in-cheek response and is terrible!!!**

Yes, it's sort of possible :)

```
template<typename T>
class Property
{
private:
    T& _value;

public:
    Property(T& value) : _value(value)
    {
    }   // eo ctor

    Property<T>& operator = (const T& val)
    {
        _value = val;
        return *this;
    };  // eo operator =

    operator const T&() const
    {
        return _value;
    };  // eo operator ()
};
```

Then declare your class, declaring properties for your members:

```
class Test
{
private:
    std::string _label;
    int         _width;

public:
    Test() : Label(_label)
           , Width(_width)
    {
    };

    Property<std::string> Label;
    Property<int>         Width;
};
```

And call C# style!

```
Test a;
a.Label = "blah";
a.Width = 5;

std::string label = a.Label;
int width = a.Width;
```

Comment: I've tried this in the past although I now tend to avoid it because people reading the code don't realise it's not just a public fields as it's not common in c++... However I was suprised to find that the compiler it usually good enough to make this just as efficient as assinging directly to the field.

Comment: Yeah, hence I had my "terrible" disclaimer.  I gave it some more thought and I'm sure it can be improved so that custom set/get functions can be provided for non-trivial sets/gets.

Comment: @jcoder I don't get it. It essentially turns `m_Test` public. Why don't just make `m_Test` public in the first place and avoid any additional coding?

Comment: I have no idea why you'd preface this as "terrible."  Granted, it's not quite so flexible as properties in C#, but when it comes to the syntactic candy factor (which is really all properties are), I think it's brilliant.  A hearty and well earned +1

Comment: This would of course need a clean way to specify the getters and setters for each property individually..

Comment: Thanks Moo-Juice, I was able to leverage this code to track down by using a breakpoint to find out how a member variable was getting set to a value that it was never supposed to be set to.  The offending callsite had a bug.

Comment: I have made an improved version of this in case anyone is interested.

Answer (score 20):

I warn you, it is not fully compatible native C++: *Microsoft-specific C++ only*.

The Microsoft compiler allows you to use `declspec(property)`, this way:

```
struct S {
   int i;
   void putprop(int j) { 
      i = j;
   }

   int getprop() {
      return i;
   }

   // here you define the property and the functions to call for it
   __declspec(property(get = getprop, put = putprop)) int the_prop;
};

int main() {
   S s;
   s.the_prop = 5;    // THERE YOU GO
   return s.the_prop;
}
```

cf Microsoft Documentation for more details: [declspec(property)](https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/cpp/cpp/property-cpp?view=vs-2019).

Comment: Still, this is great for those doing non X platform projects with MSVC! good find :)

Answer (score 10):

Moo-Juice's answer looks really cool, but has a drawback: you can't use these properties like normal expressions of type `T`, as you can in C#.

For instance,

- `a.text.c_str()` won't compile (`‘class Property<std::basic_string<char> >’ has no member named ‘c_str’`)
- `std::cout << a.text` won't compile either (`template argument deduction/substitution failed`)

I would suggest the following enhancement to `template<typename T> class Property`:

```
T& operator() ()
{
    return _value;
}
T const& operator() () const
{
    return _value;
}
```

Then you can access the property's members with `()`, such as:

```
 char const *p = a.text().c_str();
```

And you can use the property in expressions where the type must be deduced:

```
std::cout << a.text();
```

Answer (score 3):

A property in [.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.NET_Framework) is associated with a `get` and/or a `set` member function, so it's really just syntactic sugar. The closest you can get with C++ is to use overloading to give the getter and setter the same name:

```
const std::string &test() const { return text_; }
void test(const std::string &value) { text_ = value; }
```

Obviously, you will still have to provide parenthesis for the call:

```
someThing.text("blah");
String blah = someThing.text();
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes but it's vendor specific. Microsoft has declspec(property).
C++Builder's implementation is a bit more advanced (via vendor specific __property keyword) in that you could have indexed accessors (which can be of any types you wish).

Also check this out (without relying on vendor specific keywords): http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/cpp_property_indexer.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

#define PROPERTY_GET_SET(CLASS, NAME, TYPE) GetSetProperty<CLASS, TYPE> NAME() { return GetSetProperty<CLASS, TYPE>(this, &CLASS::get_##NAME, &CLASS::set_##NAME); }
#define PROPERTY_GET(CLASS, NAME, TYPE)     GetProperty<CLASS, TYPE> NAME()    { return GetProperty<CLASS, TYPE>(this, &CLASS::get_##NAME); }
#define PROPERTY_SET(CLASS, NAME, TYPE)     SetProperty<CLASS, TYPE> NAME()    { return SetProperty<CLASS, TYPE>(this, &CLASS::set_##NAME); }

template <typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
struct GetSetProperty {
    typedef TYPE (CLASS::*Getter_t)() const;
    typedef void (CLASS::*Setter_t)(TYPE);
    GetSetProperty(CLASS* instance, Getter_t getter, Setter_t setter) : m_instance(instance), m_getter(getter), m_setter(setter) {}
    operator TYPE() const { return (this->m_instance->*this->m_getter)(); }
    GetSetProperty<CLASS, TYPE>& operator=(TYPE value) { (this->m_instance->*this->m_setter)(value); return *this; }
    CLASS* const   m_instance;
    const Getter_t m_getter;
    const Setter_t m_setter;
};

template <typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
struct GetProperty {
    typedef TYPE (CLASS::*Getter_t)() const;
    GetProperty(CLASS* instance, Getter_t getter) : m_instance(instance), m_getter(getter) {}
    operator TYPE() const { return (this->m_instance->*this->m_getter)(); }
    CLASS* const   m_instance;
    const Getter_t m_getter;
};

template <typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
struct SetProperty {
    typedef void (CLASS::*Setter_t)(TYPE);
    SetProperty(CLASS* instance, Setter_t setter) : m_instance(instance), m_setter(setter) {}
    SetProperty<CLASS, TYPE>& operator=(TYPE value) { (this->m_instance->*this->m_setter)(value); return *this; }
    CLASS* const   m_instance;
    const Setter_t m_setter;
};

template <typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const GetSetProperty<CLASS, TYPE>& p) { ostr << (p.m_instance->*p.m_getter)(); return ostr; }

template <typename CLASS, typename TYPE>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, const GetProperty<CLASS, TYPE>& p) { ostr << (p.m_instance->*p.m_getter)(); return ostr; }

// ------------------------------------------------------------------

class Dummy
{
public:

    Dummy() : m_value1(42) {}

    PROPERTY_GET_SET(Dummy, Value1, int);
    PROPERTY_GET_SET(Dummy, Value2, const string&);

protected:

    virtual int           get_Value1() const { return this->m_value1; }
    virtual void          set_Value1(int value) { this->m_value1 = value; }

    virtual const string& get_Value2() const { return this->m_value2; }
    virtual void          set_Value2(const string& value) { this->m_value2 = value; }

private:

    int    m_value1;
    string m_value2;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Dummy d;

    cout << d.Value1() << endl;
    d.Value1() = 3;
    cout << d.Value1() << endl;

    cout << d.Value2() << endl;
    d.Value2() = "test";
    cout << d.Value2() << endl;

    return 0;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

By using std::function you can get pretty close. Featurewise everything is here.

First create the templated Property class:

```
#include <functional>

template<class T>
class Property
{
    std::function<T (void)> _get;
    std::function<void(const T&)> _set;
public:
    Property(
        std::function<T (void)> get,
        std::function<void(const T&)> set)
        : _get(get),
          _set(set)
    { }

    Property(
        std::function<T(void)> get)
        : _get(get),
          _set([](const unsigned int&){})
    { }

    operator T () const { return _get(); }
    void operator = (const T& t) { _set(t); }
};
```

Use the Property in a class by creating a get and a set method similar to what you would in do C#:

```
class Test
{
private:
    std::string  _label;

public:
    Property<std::string> Label = Property<std::string>
    (
        [this]()->std::string
        {
            return this->_label;
        },
        [this](const std::string& value)
        {
            this->_label = value;
        }
    );
    Property<unsigned int> LabelSize = Property<unsigned int>
    (
        [this]()->unsigned int
        {
            return this->_label.size();
        }
    );
};
```

Testing this code:

```
Test test;
test.Label = "std functional";

std::cout << "label      = " << std::string(test.Label) << std::endl
          << "label size = " << int(test.LabelSize) << std::endl;
```

will output

```
label      = std functional
label size = 14
```

I think this is as syntactic-sugar-coated as you can get it in c++ :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably the best option currently is to use the microsoft's `__declspec( property( get=get_func_name, put=put_func_name ) ) PropertyType PropertyName` attribute.

- it is also supported by clang,
- it is converted into your getter/setter when compiled (won't add any new variables),
- in use, it is the closest thing to a real property (can access property of a property...).

But if you're using other compilers, you could use macros:

```
#define PROPERTY_GEN(Class, Type, Name, GetMethod, SetMethod) \
    class Property_##Name { \
    public: \
        Property_##Name(Class* parent) : _parent(parent) { } \
        Type operator = (Type value) \
        { \
            _parent->SetMethod(value); \
            return _parent->GetMethod(); \
        } \
        operator Type() const \
        { \
            return static_cast<const Class*>(_parent)->GetMethod(); \
        } \
        Property_##Name& operator =(const Property_##Name& other) \
        { \
            operator=(other._parent->GetMethod()); return *this; \
        }; \
        Property_##Name(const Property_##Name& other) = delete; \
    private: \
        Class* _parent; \
    } Name { this };


    // PROPERTY - Declares a property with the default getter/setter method names.
    #define PROPERTY(Class, Type, Name) \
        PROPERTY_GEN(Class, Type, Name, get_##Name, set_##Name)
```

Then use them like:

```
class SomeClass
{
public:
    PROPERTY(SomeClass, int, Value)
    int get_Value() const { return _value; }
    void set_Value(int value) { _value = value; }

private:
    int _value = 0;
};


int main()
{
    SomeClass s, c;
    s.Value = 5;
    c.Value = 3 * s.Value;
    s.Value = c.Value;
}
```

You could also add other macro variants for read-only, write-only properties and read-only non-const getters. To be able to access sub-properties via ->, you could add operator-> overloads to the macro.

Compared to microsoft's __declspec(property(...)), getter and setter methods can be made private but this isn't a real advantage since client might need to take the address of a getter/setter sometimes.
There is also a disadvantage of having an additional _parent variable for every property, and you would need to explicitly define copy constructors for parent classes if they are used.

Answer (score 1):

I realize it's this question is probably too old to add another answer but to expand on Moo-Juice's answer, I've come up with a pretty neat and simple solution:

```
/// Utility for functions get, set & ptr.
template<typename TVal>
using GetFn = std::function<const TVal& (void)>;

template<typename TVal>
using SetFn = std::function<void(const TVal&)>;

template<typename TVal>
using PtrFn = std::function<TVal* (void)>;

/// The property class and each specialization utility.
template<typename TVal, bool Delegate, bool ReadOnly>
class Property;

template<typename TVal>
using PropertyGetSet = Property<TVal, false, false>;

template<typename TVal>
using PropertyDelGetSet = Property<TVal, true, false>;

template<typename TVal>
using PropertyGet = Property<TVal, false, true>;

template<typename TVal>
using PropertyDelGet = Property<TVal, true, true>;

/// <summary>
/// Property get-set.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TVal">Value type.</typeparam>
template<typename TVal>
class Property<TVal, false, false>
{
public:
    typedef TVal Value;

    Property(const TVal& val)
        : m_value(val)
    {}

    inline const TVal& Get() const { return m_value; }
    inline void Set(const TVal& val) { m_value = val; }
    inline TVal* Ptr() { return &m_value; }

private:
    TVal m_value;
};

/// <summary>
/// Property delegate get-set.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TVal">Value type.</typeparam>
template<typename TVal>
class Property<TVal, true, false>
{
public:
    typedef TVal Value;

    Property(GetFn<TVal> getFn, SetFn<TVal> setFn, PtrFn<TVal> ptrFn)
        : m_getFn(getFn)
        , m_setFn(setFn)
        , m_ptrFn(ptrFn)
    {}

    inline const TVal& Get() const { return m_getFn(); }
    inline void Set(const TVal& val) { m_setFn(val); }
    inline TVal* Ptr() { return m_ptrFn(); }

private:
    GetFn<TVal> m_getFn;
    SetFn<TVal> m_setFn;
    PtrFn<TVal> m_ptrFn;
};

/// <summary>
/// Property get.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TVal">Value type.</typeparam>
template<typename TVal>
class Property<TVal, false, true>
{
public:
    typedef TVal Value;

    Property(const TVal& val)
        : m_value(val)
    {}

    inline const TVal& Get() const { return m_value; }
    inline TVal* Ptr() { return &m_value; }

private:
    TVal m_value;
};

/// <summary>
/// Property delegate get.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TVal">Value type.</typeparam>
template<typename TVal>
class Property<TVal, true, true>
{
public:
    typedef TVal Value;

    Property(GetFn<TVal> getFn, PtrFn<TVal> ptrFn)
        : m_getFn(getFn)
        , m_ptrFn(ptrFn)
    {}

    inline const TVal& Get() const { return m_getFn(); }
    inline TVal* Ptr() { return m_ptrFn(); }

private:
    GetFn<TVal> m_getFn;
    PtrFn<TVal> m_ptrFn;
};
```

And then to use it:

```
PropertyGetSet<std::string> strGetSet = PropertyGetSet<std::string>("GetSet");

std::string m_strGetSet = "DelGetSet";
PropertyDelGetSet<std::string> strDelGetSet =
    PropertyDelGetSet<std::string>(
        [&]() -> const std::string& { return m_strGetSet; },
        [&](const std::string& val) { m_strGetSet = val; },
        [&]() { return &m_strGetSet; /* throw? */ });

// The get (read-only) version is the same but without the set function
```

Some caveats:

- The get function returns a const& so you are not able to use it for changing the value, this is by design as it would allow people to use the reference to set the value instead of the explicit Set which gives the advantage of knowing when the value is set.
- There is no syntactic sugar for the get-set-ptr functions, personally, I didn't like using operators cause it made the underlying system more obtuse, so using explicit functions lets the user know that it's a property and not something else. But if you may, you could sprinkle some operator overloads.
- All specializations have a Ptr function which will be the pointer of the data. However, when using the delegate version, you can choose to throw so anyone trying to use it will have to work around it. The reason it's there is that in the worst-case scenario you may try to use the pointer for a very particular situation, I would highly advise not to use this tho, so feel free to remove it or make an extra specialization for it.
- Lastly, it's a bit verbose, you could wrap the usage in a macro to make the syntax a bit shorter, but personally, I like it the way it is as it's more explicit that way.

**EDIT:**
You may run into the same issue I had with this design, have a look at the following link for the issue and the solution I've come up with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68563492/3339838

Answer (score 0):

Another try to enhance Moo-Juice's answer, by defining a Getter class (which the client can only get) and a Getter-Setter class which is also assignable:

```
template <typename T>
class Getter {
  protected:
    T &_value;
  public:
    Getter(T &value) : _value(value) {}
    operator const T() const {
      return _value;
    }
};

template <typename T>
class GetterSetter : public Getter<T> {
  using Getter<T>::_value;
  using Getter<T>::Getter;
  public:
  GetterSetter<T> & operator=(const T val) {
    _value = val;
    return *(this);
  } 
};
```

This gives you the option to decide which properties could be changed from outside the class, and which will only change internally.

Answer (score -1):

No, there is not. You would just create getter and setter functions:

```
someThing.setText("blah");
std::string blah = someThing.getText();
```