# Does C++11 have C#-style properties?

Tags: c#, c++, class, c++11

In C#, there is a nice syntax sugar for fields with getter and setter. Moreover, I like the auto-implemented properties which allow me to write

```
public Foo foo { get; private set; }
```

In C++ I have to write

```
private:
    Foo foo;
public:
    Foo getFoo() { return foo; }
```

Is there some such concept in the C++11 allowing me to have some syntax sugar on this?

Comment: It could be done with a couple of macros. *runs away in shame*

Comment: I just make everything public and directly access the fields as part of the public interface of the class. If a field should really be private, I preface it with an underscore, but it can still be accessed if there's a compelling reason. It's a bad idea if you have incompetent developers on your team who abuse that. *ducks*

Comment: @Eloff: Just making everything public is ALWAYS a bad idea.

Comment: a) this question is quite an old one
b) I was asking for syntax sugar, that would allow me to get rid of the parentheses
c) though the article presents valid arguments against adapting properties, whether C++ 'does or does not need' properties is very subjective. C++ is Touring-machine equivalent even without them, but that does not mean that having such syntax sugar would make C++ more productive.

Comment: This is old but relevant. The current accepted answer isn't complete, consider accepting another.

Comment: For debugging purposes, sometimes I convert a public (ick) member variable to a named operator getter and named setter (using the techniques in the answers).  Figure out the bug, and then remove that instrumentation.  It's a handy technique for tracking down bugs, but not something to leave in place for production (imo).

Comment: @Kaiserludi not necessarily, if everything is public and static you are safe =))) {sarcastices closed}

Comment: Afraid not.4321

Comment: Definitely not.

Comment: No but especially since it's read only consider `const Foo& foo(): const;`

Comment: This question is quite an old one. I was asking for syntax sugar, that would allow me to get rid of the parentheses, though the article presents valid arguments against adapting properties, whether C++ 'does or does not need' properties is very subjective. C++ is Touring-machine equivalent even without them, but that does not mean that having such syntax sugar would make C++ more productive.

Comment: There isn't, mainly because that anti-pattern is bananas. All it tends to lead to is circumvention of encapsulation. No harm in asking though.

Comment: @CinCout, I'm currently getting HTTP 500 connection refused on your link. In case it's not a transient failure: https://web.archive.org/web/20170924162758/http://seanmiddleditch.com/why-c-does-not-need-c-like-properties/

Comment: @CinCout that piece is just a subjective opinion. We all know using getters and setters work, but some of us are interested in properties. The article does not provide objective reasons for why that is _never_ useful.

Answer (score 104):

In C++ you can write your own features.
Here is an example implementation of properties using unnamed classes. [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_%28programming%29#C++)

```
struct Foo
{
    class {
        int value;
        public:
            int & operator = (const int &i) { return value = i; }
            operator int () const { return value; }
    } alpha;

    class {
        float value;
        public:
            float & operator = (const float &f) { return value = f; }
            operator float () const { return value; }
    } bravo;
};
```

You can write your own getters & setters in place and if you want holder class member access you can extend this example code.

Comment: Any ideas about how to modify this code to still have a private member variable that Foo can access internally, while the public API only exposes the property?

I could of course just make Foo a friend of alpha/beta, but then I still would have to write alpha.value, to access the value, but I would rather prefer if directly accessing the member variable from inside of Foo would feel more like accessing a member of Foo itself and not a member of a special nested property class.

Comment: @Kaiserludi Yes: in this case, make alpha and bravo private. In Foo, you can read/write with those "properties" above, but outside Foo, this wouldn't be possible anymore.  To circumvent that, make a const reference which is public. It is accessible from outside, but only for reading since it is a constant reference. The only caveat is that you'll need another name for the public const reference. I'd personally use `_alpha` for the private variable and `alpha` for the reference.

Comment: @Kapichu: not a solution, for 2 reasons. 1) In C# property getters/setters are often used to embed safeness checks that are forced to public users of the class while allowing the member functions to access the value directly. 2) const references are not free: depending on compiler/platform they will enlarge `sizeof(Foo)`.

Comment: @psx: because of limitations of this approach, I would avoid it and wait for proper addition to the standard, if it'll ever appear.

Comment: @Kapichu:
But alpha and bravo in the example code are the properties. I would like to directly access the variable itself from inside of the implementation of Foo, without the need to use a property, while I would like to only expose access through a property in the API.

Comment: @Kaiserludi Couldn't `alpha` and `bravo` just declare that `Foo` is a friend class? That way Foo (and only Foo) should be able to acces the `value` member.

Comment: @Victor: Yes, that is correct and exactly what I did in my own answer to this question, which got inspired by this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26265069/404734

Comment: @Kaiserludi I missed that! The text emphasized the `private`-ness of the setter, but it does stand to reason that you had to solve the problem of access from the parent because someone needs to set it :)

Comment: What about if we want it to access an element from the parent struct?

Comment: This work for the wrapped values being primitive properties like `int` and `float`, but won't work if the wrapper values have methods.

Answer (score 70):

C++ doesn't have this built in, you can **define a template** to mimic properties functionality:

```
template <typename T>
class Property {
public:
    virtual ~Property() {}  //C++11: use override and =default;
    virtual T& operator= (const T& f) { return value = f; }
    virtual const T& operator() () const { return value; }
    virtual explicit operator const T& () const { return value; }
    virtual T* operator->() { return &value; }
protected:
    T value;
};
```

To **define a property**:

```
Property<float> x;
```

To implement a **custom getter/setter** just inherit:

```
class : public Property<float> {
    virtual float & operator = (const float &f) { /*custom code*/ return value = f; }
    virtual operator float const & () const { /*custom code*/ return value; }
} y;
```

To define a **read-only property**:

```
template <typename T>
class ReadOnlyProperty {
public:
    virtual ~ReadOnlyProperty() {}
    virtual operator T const & () const { return value; }
protected:
    T value;
};
```

And to **use it in class `Owner`**:

```
class Owner {
public:
    class : public ReadOnlyProperty<float> { friend class Owner; } x;
    Owner() { x.value = 8; }
};
```

You could define some of the above in **macros** to make it more concise.

Comment: I'm curious if this compiles-down to a zero-cost feature, I don't know if wrapping each data-member in a class instance will result in the same kind of structure-packing, for example.

Comment: The "custom getter/setter" logic could be made syntactically cleaner by the use of lambda functions, unfortunately you cannot define a lambda outside of an executable context in C++ (yet!) so without using a preprocessor macro you end up with code that's just as fiddly as dumb getters/setters, which is unfortunate.

Comment: The "class: ..." in the last example is interesting, and missing from the other examples. It creates the necessary friend-declaration - without introducing a new class name.

Comment: A big difference between this and the 2010-Nov-19 answer is that this enables overriding the getter or setter on a case-by-case basis.  That way one could vet the input to be in range, or to send a change notification out to change event listeners, or a place to hang a breakpoint.

Comment: Note that the `virtual` is *probably* unnecessary for most use cases, since a Property is unlikely to be use polymorphically.

Comment: Unless there's a good reason not to use `virtual` I'd keep it, just so I wouldn't need to use the word 'probably'...

Comment: @MichaelLitvin: if you have a chance, please check my question https://stackoverflow.com/q/70149139/3358488 which is a followup of your answer pointing out a limitation.

Comment: This (and the other most voted question) seem incorrect. It will work for primitive types, but not for `T` being a class with methods. If I have `Property<Foo> prop;` trying to invoke a `Foo` method won't work: `prop.foo_ method()` does not compile.

Answer (score 41):

There is nothing in the C++ language that will work across all platforms and compilers.

But if you're willing to break cross-platform compatibility and commit to a specific compiler you may be able to use such syntax, for example [in Microsoft Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx) you can do

```
// declspec_property.cpp  
struct S {  
   int i;  
   void putprop(int j) {   
      i = j;  
   }  

   int getprop() {  
      return i;  
   }  

   __declspec(property(get = getprop, put = putprop)) int the_prop;  
};  

int main() {  
   S s;  
   s.the_prop = 5;  
   return s.the_prop;  
}
```

Comment: This also [works with clang](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1MSPropertyDecl.html)

Comment: Great answer! I also appreciate how you pointed out the major risk of breaking functionality too.

Answer (score 20):

With C++11 you can define a Property class template and use it like this:

```
class Test{
public:
  Property<int, Test> Number{this,&Test::setNumber,&Test::getNumber};

private:
  int itsNumber;

  void setNumber(int theNumber)
    { itsNumber = theNumber; }

  int getNumber() const
    { return itsNumber; }
};
```

And here ist the Property class template.

```
template<typename T, typename C>
class Property{
public:
  using SetterType = void (C::*)(T);
  using GetterType = T (C::*)() const;

  Property(C* theObject, SetterType theSetter, GetterType theGetter)
   :itsObject(theObject),
    itsSetter(theSetter),
    itsGetter(theGetter)
    { }

  operator T() const
    { return (itsObject->*itsGetter)(); }

  C& operator = (T theValue) {
    (itsObject->*itsSetter)(theValue);
    return *itsObject;
  }

private:
  C* const itsObject;
  SetterType const itsSetter;
  GetterType const itsGetter;
};
```

Comment: what does `C::*` mean? I have never seen anything like it before?

Comment: It's a pointer to a non-static member function in class `C`. This is similar to a plain function pointer but in order to call the member function you need to provide an object on which the function is called. This is achieved with the line `itsObject->*itsSetter(theValue)` in the example above. See [here](https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/article.php/c17401/C-Tutorial-PointertoMember-Function.htm) for a more detailed description of this feature.

Comment: @Niceman, is there an example of usage? It appears to be very costly to have as a member. It's not particularly useful as a static member, either.

Answer (score 19):

You can emulate getter and setter to some extent by having a member of dedicated type and overriding `operator(type)` and `operator=` for it. Whether it's a good idea is another question and I'm going to `+1` Kerrek SB's answer to express my opinion thereon :)

Comment: You can emulate calling a method upon assigning-to or reading-from by such type but you can't distinguish who calls the assign operation (to prohibit it if it's not the field owner) - what I am trying to do by specifying different access level for getter and setter.

Comment: @Flavius: Just add a `friend` to the field owner.

Answer (score 18):

Maybe have a look at the property class I have assembled during the last hours: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/c11-feedback-on-my-approach-to-c-like-class-properties

It allows you to have properties behaving like this:

```
CTestClass myClass = CTestClass();

myClass.AspectRatio = 1.4;
myClass.Left = 20;
myClass.Right = 80;
myClass.AspectRatio = myClass.AspectRatio * (myClass.Right - myClass.Left);
```

Comment: Nice, however although this allows user-defined accessors there is not the public getter/private setter feature I was looking for.

Answer (score 18):

As many other have already said, there's no built-in support in the language. However, if you are targeting the Microsoft C++ compiler you can take advantage of the Microsoft-specific extension for properties which is documented [here.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/property-cpp)

This is the example from the linked page:

```
// declspec_property.cpp
struct S {
   int i;
   void putprop(int j) { 
      i = j;
   }

   int getprop() {
      return i;
   }

   __declspec(property(get = getprop, put = putprop)) int the_prop;
};

int main() {
   S s;
   s.the_prop = 5;
   return s.the_prop;
}
```

Answer (score 16):

No, C++ has no concept of properties.  Though it can be awkward to define and call getThis() or setThat(value), you are making a statement to the consumer of those methods that some functionality may occur.  Accessing fields in C++, on the other hand, tells the consumer that no additional or unexpected functionality will occur.  Properties would make this less obvious as property access at first glance appears to react like a field, but in fact reacts like a method.

As an aside, I was working in a .NET application (a very well known CMS) attempting to create a customer membership system.  Due to the way they had used properties for their user objects, actions were firing off that I hadn't anticipated, causing my implementations to execute in bizarre ways including infinite recursion.  This was because their user objects made calls to the data access layer or some global caching system when attempting to access simple things like StreetAddress.  Their entire system was founded on what I would call an abuse of properties.  Had they have used methods instead of properties, I think I would have figured out what was going wrong much more quickly.  Had they have used fields (or at least made their properties behave more like fields), I think the system would have been easier to extend and maintain.

[Edit]  Changed my thoughts.  I'd had a bad day and went a bit on a rant.  This cleanup should be more professional.

Comment: While this post is quite old, the problem you described isn't necessarily properties doing stuff, but properties doing stuff that had a wide array of side-effects. A very simple logic that is usually not harmful is to include checks in a setter, and fire exceptions if assignment is outside of the allowed range. Another use case is just marking an object dirty. Although WPF heavily relies on not only marking dirty, but also firing events, which might easily lead to the problems you were describing.

Answer (score 13):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/23109533/404734 here is a version with a public getter and a private setter:

```
struct Foo
{
    class
    {
            int value;
            int& operator= (const int& i) { return value = i; }
            friend struct Foo;
        public:
            operator int() const { return value; }
    } alpha;
};
```

Answer (score 7):

You probably know that but I would simply do the following:

```
class Person {
public:
    std::string name() {
        return _name;
    }
    void name(std::string value) {
        _name = value;
    }
private:
    std::string _name;
};
```

This approach is simple, uses no clever tricks and it gets the job done!

*The issue though is that some people don't like to prefix their private fields with an underscore and so they can't really use this approach, but fortunately for these who do, it's really straightforward. :)*

The get and set prefixes doesn't add clarity to your API but making them more verbose and the reason I don't think they add useful information is because when someone needs to use an API if the API makes sense she will probably realize what it does without the prefixes.

One more thing, it's easy to grasp that these are properties because `name` isn't a verb.

Worst case scenario, if the APIs are consistent and the person didn't realize that `name()` is an accessor and `name(value)` is a mutator then she will only have to look it up once in the documentation to understand the pattern.

As much as I love C# I don't think C++ needs properties at all!

Comment: Your mutators make sense if one uses `foo(bar)` (instead of the slower `foo = bar`), but your accessors have nothing to do with properties at all...

Comment: @Matthias Stating that it doesn't have anything to do with properties at all, doesn't tell me anything, can you elaborate? besides I didn't try to compare them but if you need a mutator and accessor you can use this convention.

Comment: The question is about the software concept of Properties. Properties can be used as if they are public data members (usage), but they are actually special methods called accessors (declaration). Your solution sticks to methods (ordinary getters/setters) for the declaration and the usage. So this is, first of all, definitely not the usage the OP is asking for, but rather some strange and unconventional naming convention (and thus, secondly, also no syntactic sugar).

Comment: As a minor side effect, your mutator surprisingly works as a Property, since in C++ one best initializes with `foo(bar)` instead of `foo=bar` which can be achieved with a `void foo(Bar bar)` mutator method on a `_foo` member variable.

Comment: @Matthias I know what are properties, I've been writing C++ quite a bit and C# for over a decade, I'm not arguing about the benefit of properties and what they are but I never REALLY needed them in C++, in fact you're saying that they can be used as public data and that's mostly true but there are cases in C# where you can't even use properties directly, like passing a property by ref whereas with a public field, you can.

Comment: @Matthias The OP asked whether C++11 has some syntactic sugar to accessors and mutators and the REAL answer here is C++ doesn't have anything close to it baked in so you can either mimic it and generally this means you need to use an unconventional mechanism that for each library or application you write you will have to add this template you wrote into the project or you can simply use a convention based approach that already exist and used in C++ for many years and stick with it which is what I decided to do the only difference is I gave it a twist and got rid of the prefixes.

Comment: @Matthias I understand that the approach isn't a syntactic sugar to accessors and mutators and in practice none of the solutions here are really syntactic sugar, yes, they allow the OP to mimic properties to some extent but they also bring quite a bit of complexity so after reading the solutions here, I thought that some of them were too complex relatively to the problem and posted a solution that works for me for many years!

Comment: @Matthias Whether this is "unconventional naming convention" is really irrelevant as long as you, your team, customers understand it, the most important thing is consistency, stick to the patterns that works for you.

Answer (score 5):

This is not exactly a property, but it does what you want the simple way:

```
class Foo {
  int x;
public:
  const int& X;
  Foo() : X(x) {
    ...
  }
};
```

Here the big X behaves like `public int X { get; private set; }` in C# syntax. If you want full-blown properties, I made a first shot to implement them [here](https://github.com/janturon/CPP-Properties).

Comment: This is not a good idea. Whenever you make a copy of an object of this class, the reference `X` of the new object will still point to the member of the old object, because it is just copied like a pointer member. This is bad in itself, but when the old object gets deleted, you get memory corruption on top of it. To make this work, you would have to also implement your own copy constructor, assignment operator and move constructor.

Answer (score 4):

Nope.. 
But you should consider if it`s just get : set function and no additional task preformed inside get:set methods just make it public.

Answer (score 2):

I collected the ideas from multiple C++ sources and put it into a nice, still quite simple example for getters/setters in C++:

```
class Canvas { public:
    void resize() {
        cout << "resize to " << width << " " << height << endl;
    }

    Canvas(int w, int h) : width(*this), height(*this) {
        cout << "new canvas " << w << " " << h << endl;
        width.value = w;
        height.value = h;
    }

    class Width { public:
        Canvas& canvas;
        int value;
        Width(Canvas& canvas): canvas(canvas) {}
        int & operator = (const int &i) {
            value = i;
            canvas.resize();
            return value;
        }
        operator int () const {
            return value;
        }
    } width;

    class Height { public:
        Canvas& canvas;
        int value;
        Height(Canvas& canvas): canvas(canvas) {}
        int & operator = (const int &i) {
            value = i;
            canvas.resize();
            return value;
        }
        operator int () const {
            return value;
        }
    } height;
};

int main() {
    Canvas canvas(256, 256);
    canvas.width = 128;
    canvas.height = 64;
}
```

Output:

```
new canvas 256 256
resize to 128 256
resize to 128 64
```

You can test it online here: http://codepad.org/zosxqjTX

Comment: There is a memory overhead for keeping self refrences, + an akward ctor syntax.

Comment: To propose properties? I guess there've been a bunch of rejected such proposals.

Comment: @Red.Wave Bow down to the lord and master of rejection then. Welcome to C++. Clang and MSVC have custom extensions for properties, if you don't want the self references.

Comment: I can never bow. Not every feature is even appropariate I think. To me Objects are far more than a pair of setter+getter functions. I have tried own implementations avoiding the unnecessary permanent memory overhead, but the syntax and chore of declaring instances was not satisfactory; I was drawn to using declarative macros, but I am not a big fan of macros anyhow. And my approach finally, led to porperties accessed with function syntax, which many including myself don't approve.

Answer (score 1):

There are a set of macros written [Here](https://github.com/tejusadiga2004/NTProperty). THis has convinient property declarations for value types, reference types, read only types, strong and weak types.

```
class MyClass {

 // Use assign for value types.
 NTPropertyAssign(int, StudentId)

 public:
 ...

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does you class really need to enforce some invariant or is it just a logical grouping of member elements?  If it is the latter you should consider making the thing a struct and accessing the members directly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another implementation of properties in c++ (std=c++17)

[propertycpp@github](https://github.com/oskarirauta/propertycpp)

It provides a example which shows how to create properties, either publicly available as readonly where build-time exception is handled when attempting to write on property; example that shows "default" property with read&write access, example of dynamic getter (alters actual value), and dynamic readonly.

Initializing a property is far from nice...