# Creating a class member that is automatically calculated from other class members?

Tags: c++, class

1. I'm an absolute newbee when it comes to programming and I'm trying to teach myself the basics by just solving some easy "problems" in C++.
2. I have searched the web for an exact answer to my question before posting it here and haven't found one so far, however that may be because of (1).

So, what I'm looking for is a way to declare a class member that gets automatically calculated from other members of the same class, so that the calculated class member can be used just like an explicitly defined class member would. For example imagine a struct called creature that has the properties/members creature.numberofhands, creature.fingersperhand and finally the property creature.totalfingers that automatically gets calculated from the above members.

Heres an example of the closest I got to what I wanted to achieve:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef struct creature {
    int numberofhands;
    int fingersperhand;
    int totalfingers();
} creature;    

int creature::totalfingers()
{
    return numberofhands * fingersperhand;
};

int main()
{
    creature human;
    human.numberofhands = 2;
    human.fingersperhand = 5;

    printf("%d",human.totalfingers());
    return(0);
}
```

What's really annoying me about this, is that I have to treat the calculated one DIFFERENTLY from the explicitly defined ones, i.e. I have to put "()" after it.
How can I change the code, so I can use: human.totalfingers without ever explicitly defining it?

Comment: You don't need `typedef struct` in C++.

Comment: You may change you regular member to also use `()`, or create a proxy object with `operator int()`, but the last one won't works with ellipsis of `printf` without help.

Comment: I wouldn't actually do this, but for funsises you could define a token for each function you want to call with the same syntax as a variable `#define totalNoOfFingers creature::totalfingers()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use public member functions and make the actual properties hidden.
Something like this:

```
class Creature {
public:
    Creature(int numhands, int fingersperhand) // constructor
        : m_numhands{numhands}, m_fingersperhand{fingersperhand}
        { }
    int fingersPerHand() const { return m_fingersperhand; }
    int numberOfHands() const { return m_numhands; }
    int totalFingers() const { return numberOfHands() * fingersPerHand(); }

private:
    const int m_numhands;
    const int m_fingersperhand;
};
```

The private member variables are an implementation detail. Users of the class just use the three public member functions to get the different number of fingers after construction and don't need to care that two of them are returning constant stored numbers and the third returns a calculated value - that's irrelevant to users.

An example of use:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    Creature human{2, 5};
    std::cout << "A human has "
        << human.totalFingers() << " fingers. "
        << human.fingersPerHand() << " on each of their "
        << human.numberOfHands() << " hands.\n";
    return 0;
}
```

*If* - as per your comment - you don't want to use a constructor (although that's the safest way to ensure you don't forget to initialize a member), you can modify the class like this:

```
class CreatureV2 {
public:
    int fingersPerHand() const { return m_fingersperhand; }
    int numberOfHands() const { return m_numhands; }
    int totalFingers() const { return numberOfHands() * fingersPerHand(); }

    void setFingersPerHand(int num) { m_fingersperhand = num; }
    void setNumberOfHands(int num) { m_numhands = num; }

private:
    // Note: these are no longer `const` and I've given them default
    // values matching a human, so if you do nothing you'll get
    // human hands.
    int m_numhands = 2;
    int m_fingersperhand = 5;
};
```

Example of use of the modified class:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    CreatureV2 human;
    std::cout << "A human has "
        << human.totalFingers() << " fingers. "
        << human.fingersPerHand() << " on each of their "
        << human.numberOfHands() << " hands.\n";

    CreatureV2 monster;
    monster.setFingersPerHand(7);
    monster.setNumberOfHands(5);
    std::cout << "A monster has "
        << monster.totalFingers() << " fingers. "
        << monster.fingersPerHand() << " on each of their "
        << monster.numberOfHands() << " hands.\n";

    CreatureV2 freak;
    freak.setFingersPerHand(9);
    // Note: I forgot to specify the number of hands, so a freak get 
    // the default 2.
    std::cout << "A freak has "
        << freak.totalFingers() << " fingers. "
        << freak.fingersPerHand() << " on each of their "
        << freak.numberOfHands() << " hands.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Note: all of the above assumes you are using a modern C++14 compiler.

Comment: How do I define a certain creature with this way of doing it?

Comment: Okay, I see you added an example of use. However, now the problem I see is that I have to remember the order in which I declared members of "creature" when I define "human", instead of defining it via their "names".
What if I have like 50 members with easy to remember names (like hands, feet, limbs, noses, ears etc.) but no particular order that can be easily deduced?

Comment: @TrveBlack I hope the answer answers your question fully now :-)

Comment: The problem with this approach is that the derived property has to be recomputed every time it is accessed. An ideal solution would have it computed only when the underlying variables change. This matters if the computation involved is time-consuming.

Answer (score 2):

What you have described is one of the reasons why encapsulation and "member variables should be private" is the recommended way of doing things in C++.

If every variable is accessed through a function, then everything is consistent, and refactoring from a member variable to a computation is possible.

Some languages, like C# or D, have the concept of "properties", which provide a way around the issue, but C++ does not have such a construct.

Answer (score 2):

For fun, the proxy way to avoid extra parenthesis, (but with some extra costs):

```
class RefMul
{
public:
    RefMul(int& a, int& b) : a(a), b(b) {}

    operator int() const { return a * b; }

private:
    int& a;
    int& b;
};

struct creature {
    int numberofhands;
    int fingersperhand;
    RefMul totalfingers{numberofhands, fingersperhand};
};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab7823f85b6cc3d9)

Note: to use `RefMul` with `printf`, you have to cast to `int`:

```
printf("%d", int(human.totalfingers));
```

That cast would not be required if you use c++ way to print:

```
std::cout << human.totalfingers;
```

Comment: While this technically answers the question, using something like this in the context presented in the question is really, really bad design.

Comment: @Frank: I agree that it should not be used.

Answer (score 1):

If you're after consistency, you can make your changes the other way around. Replace the two member variables with constant methods which simply return copies of the member variables. That way, the way you access data is consistent and you don't have to worry about some code changing the values of the member variables when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Others have provided very good answers. If you are looking for consistency, probably the easiest way is to make use of member functions (as @Jesper Juhl has answered).

On the other hand, if you strictly want to use class members that are calculated automatically from other members, you can use properties. Properties (as are defined in C# and Groovy) are not a standard feature of C++ but there are ways to implement them in C++. [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties) has a very good overview of the ways that properties can be defined and used in C++. My favorite way of defining properties is taking advantage of Microsoft-specific extension for properties in Visual C++ (obviously, this approach is specific to Microsoft Visual C++). A documentation of properties in Visual C++ can be found in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yhfk0thd.aspx). Using properties in Visual C++, your code can be modified to:

```
struct creature {
    int numberofhands; // use of public member variables are generally discouraged
    int fingersperhand;

    __declspec(property(get = get_totalfingers)) // Microsoft-specific
    int totalfingers;

private:
    int fingers;
    int get_totalfingers() 
    {
        return numberofhands * fingersperhand; // This is where the automatic calculation takes place. 
    }
};
```

This class can be used like this:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    creature martian;
    martian.numberofhands = 2;
    martian.fingersperhand = 4; // Marvin the Martian had 4!

    // This line will print 8
    std::cout << "Total fingers: " << martian.totalfingers << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

As I said earlier, properties are not a standard feature of C++ but there are ways to get them in C++ which either rely on smart tricks or using compiler-specific features. IMHO, using simple functions (as @Jesper Juhl described) is a better alternative.