# OpenCV C++ Mat class rows and cols - are they member variables (and related questions)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm experiencing some confusion on how rows and cols are implemented in OpenCV's Mat class, hopefully somebody can provide some clarification.

When using the Mat class, rows and cols can't have () after them, i.e.:

```
cv::Mat imgSomeImage;
imgSomeImage = cv::imread("some_image.png");

// this line works
std::cout << "num rows = " << imgSomeImage.rows << "\n";

// this line does not compile, only difference is the () after rows
std::cout << "num rows = " << imgSomeImage.rows() << "\n";
```

Having familiarity with .NET, I at first figured rows and cols must be properties, but after reading this:

[Does C++11 have C#-style properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties)

it seems C++ does not have an equivalent, at least not without adding a class to mimic .NET properties, which as far as I could find, OpenCV does not do.

So, I figured Mat rows and cols must be member variables, and went to the OpenCV source for confirmation.

Checking mat.hpp:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp

line 217 and 218:

```
int cols(int i=-1) const;
int rows(int i=-1) const;
```

is where I get unclear on things.  I've seen this many times:

```
// declare a member variable with a default value of -1
int cols = -1;
```

or this:

```
const int SOME_CONSTANT = 123;
```

and if cols should be read-only to the outside world, I would have figured something like this:

```
// member variable
private:
    int _cols;

// getter
public:
    int cols() { return _cols; }
```

Looking at the usage of rows and cols in matrix.cpp:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/src/matrix.cpp

for example, line 395:

```
    if( d == 2 && rows == _sizes[0] && cols == _sizes[1] )
```

or line 498:

```
    cols = _colRange.size();
```

and many similar examples, it seems these are indeed member variables, but I still am unclear on the line 217 & 218 syntax:

```
int cols(int i=-1) const;
int rows(int i=-1) const;
```

Can somebody clarify if these are member variables and what is going on syntax-wise on the declaration line?

Comment: the lines you are looking at are not from `Mat`. `Mat::row(int)` and `Mat::col(int)` are at lines 1081 and 1090

Comment: Please be more specific than "does not compile". Copy and paste the error message.

Comment: @tobi303, I think they're at line 2047, see Miki's answer below.  Since you mentioned it, taking line 1081 as an example, I still don't understand the "Mat row(int y) const;" syntax, if somebody could explain what this is doing and how this syntax is valid that would be great.

Comment: Mat also has `row(int)` and `col(int)`, those are member functions. As opposed to the class you were looking at they dont have default parameters, thus when calling them you need to pass a parameter, like `some_mat.row(3);`, but I also dont know what they are doing, but there must be documentation somewhere, which is usually easier to understand that the code ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at `_InputArray`.

If you look at the `Mat`, you'll see at line [2047](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L2047) that `rows` and `cols` are in fact member variables:

```
int rows, cols;
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  These 3,000+ line .h files can be a bit difficult to navigate sometimes.  If anybody is wondering, for mat.hpp https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp , class _InputArray begins on line 148, class _OutputArray begins on line 277, class _InputOutputArray begins on line 359, class MatAllocator begins on line 435, MatCommaInitializer_ begins on line 480, class Mat itself finally begins on line 772, Mat_ begins on line 2135, UMat begins on line 2339, . . . (there are many more but I'm out of characters in my response!)