# Possible to capture events on destructive assignment of some object property in C++(17)?

Tags: c++

In C++(17), I need to capture events on destructive assignment of some object property. In other words, listening updates of some object property.

I can do this in JavaScript, and need to do the same on C++17.

The below is a sample code of JavaScript.

```
const obj = {}; //some object
Object.defineProperties(obj,
      {
        t: { //obj.t
          get() {
            return obj.t;
          },
          //here capturing destructive assignment of some object property
          set(newT) {   
            //do something
          }
        }
      });
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Self answer.

I found this is basically the problem to design setter of property in C++, where in default, there is no property feature in C++ which I have totally forgotten.

So here is the answer:

https://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/article.php/c4031/Implementing-a-Property-in-C.htm

[Does C++11 have C#-style properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)