# Is there a way to call member's getter/setter in C++ without parentheses?

Tags: c++, oop, operator-overloading, overloading, getter-setter

I want to run some GLSL code **as** a C++ code, by `#including` it in a C++ application, without modification. It has no special pragmas and so on, but it has some vector types. For example `vec3` and `vec4`, that simply means tuple of 3 and 4 floats, respectively, that is contig in memory and convenient for some linear algebra tasks.

Pretty everything could be done with operator overloading, except one thing. 
Consider that `vec4 a` has 4 float members: `a.x`, `a.y`, `a.z` and `a.w`;

In glsl, there is a popular notation `a.xyz`, that means "take `a.x,a.y,a.z` and construct vec3 from them."

Some languages, like Object oriented versions of Pascal(Delphi) has such facility: such members are defined with `property` keyword in there. So when compiler meets it, it calls getter, when it meets assigment - it calls setter, and everything looks like you are reading or writing a regular member variable.

How can we write so in C++?

---

```
class vec4 {
public:
    float x,y,z,w;
    property xyz read=get_xyz write=set_xyz; // ??? is there some way?
protected:
    vec3 get_xyz() const { return vec3(x, y, z); }
    void set_xyz(const vec3& v) { x = v.x; y=v.y; z=v.z; }
};
```

In code then I want to write getter like this:

```
vec4 a(1,2,3,4);
auto b = a.xyz; // b = a.get_xyz();
```

`b` now is of type `vec3` and has `x==1`, `y==2`, `z==3`;

And setter like this:

```
vec4 a(1,2,3,4);
a.xyz=vec3(5,6,7); // a.set_xyz(vec3(5,6,7));
```

`a` now has `x==5`, `y==6`, `z==7` and `w==1`;

---

**How could I support such syntax?**

Comment: I have never seen that done in c++. In the case of the setter, I guess one could overload operator= for that type but... I hardly see that as a good idea.

Comment: Seems that you're looking about _property_ syntax as supported in languages like c# or delphi. C++ doesn't support that.

Comment: You can do something like C# properties in C++.  Michael Litvin shows an example in his [template to mimic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478633/4641116) answer.  I would not recommend you do that, however.  It is not idiomatic C++.

Comment: You cannot just invent new syntax in C++, no.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Just asked, maybe for new features in the new standart. By the way, you may not compare C# to Delphi. Because C# was originated as interpretator, (more like qbasic simulator toy for msdos). And delphi is a pascal extension, (turbo/borland pascal, that originally was compiled directly to 16-bit asm) and more like C/C++ - supporting those low level features like working with pointers, bit operations, so on. Delphi is just the closest "normal"  language (not java/c#/..) that support properties. I cann't see any reason and disappointed that C++19 still lacks such syntactic sugar...

Comment: Swizzling has been done in C++ (glm has done it with GLSL style vectors) but it produces huge slow code. But that doesn’t address the underlying issue, GLSL is very different from C++, for one it is designed to be a highly parallel language, it also only accepts its inputs through in/out/uniform variables; HLSL uses a more conventional function style syntax, but that probably won’t help much because they’re both supposed to run on the GPU. If you want there is a reference compiler for GLSL, and you may be able to find a debugger for NVidia GPU’s, but overall this is an XY problem.

Comment: @vandench Ultimate goal is to compile compute shader (without any pragmas, uniforms, and special things, except properties) with msvc/gcc without modification. Computation speed, memory usage and so on - does not matter.

Comment: Have you considered framebuffers? It lets you use shaders properly and saves the data. If a framebuffer isn’t the right concept compute shaders are also a viable option. Otherwise you’re going to need to either write a GLSL compiler or modify an existing one.

Comment: @vandench I dont want to use shader "properly" (eg in GL/Vulkan enviroment). I even dont want to use its main function (that is supposed to be called in parallel for every data element). All I want - is to mimic `.xyz` notation in C++, at cost of speed/memory/whatever. Its theoretical syntetic question, exactly stated excersize without any other goal (Its not a part of any project/product)

Comment: @xakepp35 Fully mimicking `.xyz` notation is harder than you think. In GLSL you can do things like `foo.yzxx` (which does `vec4(foo.y, foo.z, foo.x, foo.x)`). Even if you found a way to create something that looks like properties, you'd have to write hundreds of those 'properties' to cover every letter combination.

Comment: In that case you want to look at GLM, it’s designed to be similar to GLSL vectors and even has swizzling, but it’s not implemented as a compiler extension for syntactic sugar, it’s added using some terrifying templates. It works, but you don’t want to know how.

Comment: @vandench thanks, I will take a look!

Comment: @2785528 `TellMonitor tm = new TellMonitor("Time Vortex Hocus", 2, alarm);
tm.setValue(3);` :-/ I would prefer even shorter syntax `tm.Value=3;` if a `value` is a private member, and `Value` coould be defined as a `property` with `set=setValue` and `get=getValue` That would allow to tie some logic (even an api call) to a set/get, while keeping syntax just like you are accessing/assigning just a member! Just complaining - why they cant just put such a simple thing in a new standart?!

Answer (score 0):

It's a sad fact, that such a mature, powerful and widely-used C++ language has no `property` support. Even Delphi has.. Luckily, I've managed to solve task (To compile compute glsl shader as C++ without modifying GLSL source). I think it would not have speed/memory penalty, related to creating proxy objects, and would be easily optimizable by compiler (though this is not needed).

I've found following solution:

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZHfToMwFIev26c4yW7apDJ1uCXb9FXMoeBGZKWBVv4sPDu2lDmN05ueHz2nfB9Fan13kHIcF7mShU0z2OdlbaoMTy@ULnSFhxOCRvnOtK2PAmJOZYF1DR@ZXMGZapsUudxS8laUaKAVneh3lPgu43Ae5njpQgjdJfQc3FnSspYL6Fjn1p71nBJ3ctjRKyv@zrIqL5XbIMSpWmmm@GXg394LaJwGGfwyqbad9xqCW3x1i/92u4SG33J0BNZcTX/eVak5pbkycMJceZibCyYxIHsQ8Chg5W/T@6E1JSTwDBh5S1gu56dDZl7dDpumapNut7K0BvZ7SKI2lC6U3pdpIlNp4T/0X6DnOML0a54ErAVs@MTFqJ6Zc28tNvw3HgMeAx4DHqPmhkWVGVspuN/RYRw/AQ)

```
#include <iostream>

#pragma pack(push, 4)
class vec3 {
public:
    float x,y,z;
    vec3() {}
    vec3(float x, float y, float z) :
        x(x), y(y), z(z)
    {}
};

class vec4 {
public:
    union {
        struct {
            float x, y, z, w;
        };
        vec3 xyz;
    };
    vec4() {}
    vec4(float x, float y, float z, float w):
        x(x), y(y), z(z), w(w)
    {}
};

#pragma pack(pop)

int main() {
    {
        vec4 a(1, 2, 3, 4);
        auto b = a.xyz; // b = a.get_xyz();
        std::cout << b.x << b.y << b.z << std::endl;
    }
    {
        vec4 a(1, 2, 3, 4);
        a.xyz = vec3(5, 6, 7); // a.set_xyz(vec3(5,6,7));
        std::cout << a.x << a.y << a.z << a.w << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that C++ disallows (undefined behavior) writing to one union member and reading from a different union member.

Comment: @Eljay Thanks for important notice. Feel free to post another possible solution, if you have one by hand. Just copy my `main()` function - it must work without modification, producing same output (as TIO's `gcc` does). Speed and memory usage are of no concenrs (this is theoretical excercise).

Comment: When in Rome...  I'd use getter and setter methods with the parentheses, because that's kind of C++ won't confuse any other C++ developer.  I'd use `vec3 xyz() const` as the getter, and provide both `xyz(vec3)` and `xyz(float x, float y, float z)` as the setters.  Although my druthers would be to make the vec3 and vec4 both immutable, and setters would be factories that return a new vec3 or vec4 -- but that's a whole 'nother topic.

Comment: @Eljay now imagine window.title.. It must feel to you as a string. `window.title="Hello";` seems to be most obvious to C++.. oh sorry, even to non-programmer... Under the hood, on win32 api its not even a variable! You have to call `SetWindowTextA(hWnd, newWindowTitle.c_str())`.. on the getter side even worse: you want to go like `std::string s(256, '\0'); auto newLen=GetWindowTextA(hWnd, &s[0], s.size()); s.resize(newLen); return s;` All this *may* and *should* be exposed as a `title` property of your nice `window` class..

Comment: @Eljay That's a motivation example. As per task, your variant is not working. It gives compilation error on `auto b = a.xyz` statement, that reads: *error C3867:  'vec4::xyz': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member* So I can not accept it as a solution.