# Using std::enable_if or similar method on member variable

Tags: c++, variables, sfinae

Currently I have a custom vector class as follows:

```
template<int D, typename T = float>
class Vec
{
    private:

        T data[D];

    public:

        Vec(T initial = 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < D; ++i)
            {
                data[i] = initial;
            }
        }

        // Misc. operator overloads
};

using Vec2 = Vec<2>;
using Vec3 = Vec<3>;
using Vec4 = Vec<4>;
```

I would like to add a few member variables, namely `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w`
, that will point to the first, second, third, and fourth positions in the vector respectively. Ideally, those variables would only be visible if the vector was declared with enough dimensions. I.e. a 2D vector would not have access to `Vec<D, T>::z`.

What I have found to work:

```
template<int D2 = D, typename  T2 = typename std::enable_if<(D2 > 0), T*>::type>
T2 x(){ return &data[0];}
template<int D2 = D, typename  T2 = typename std::enable_if<(D2 > 1), T*>::type>
T2 y(){ return &data[1];}
template<int D2 = D, typename  T2 = typename std::enable_if<(D2 > 2), T*>::type>
T2 z(){ return &data[2];}
template<int D2 = D, typename  T2 = typename std::enable_if<(D2 > 3), T*>::type>
T2 w(){ return &data[3];}
```

As you can see, c++ will have a bit of a midlife crisis if I try to input the template parameters `D` and `T` as-is so I'm forced to essentially redefine each of them. And I know what I'm about to say is ludicrous but I'd really like for `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` to be variables instead of functions, because in my opinion `vec.x` looks nicer than `vec.x()` (nitpicky I know).

I can't use this solution because variables can't have templates, only classes and functions. What I'm currently playing with is this:

```
typename std::conditional<(D > 0), T*, std::nullptr_t>::type x = &data[0];
typename std::conditional<(D > 1), T*, std::nullptr_t>::type y = &data[1];
typename std::conditional<(D > 2), T*, std::nullptr_t>::type z = &data[2];
typename std::conditional<(D > 3), T*, std::nullptr_t>::type w = &data[3];
```

I had decided to use `std::nullptr_t` as the fallback cast because I wanted a type that floats, ints, etc. couldn't be cast to, alas I've come to discover that this is no good. I need a means of preventing `x`, `y`, `z`, and `w` from being evaluated until they're called, otherwise any instance of Vec with less than 4 dimensions will throw a compiler error on the line that `w` is being evaluated on, meaning regardless of whether I attempt to call `w`, it is being evaluated during compilation and will error.

**I'm looking for a solution that either prevents a variable from being evaluated unless it is being called (a solution that isn't called a function) or a solution that will alow me to make a member variable completely invisible outside the class under specific circumstances.**

Edit: I've had an additional go at it, no success:

```
private:

        T data[D];

        auto getW(){return &data[4];};

    public:

        typename std::conditional<(D > 3), T*, std::nullptr_t>::type w = getW();
```

This still throws a compilation error for any instance of `class Vec` with less than 4 dimesions. Now I'm really confused. The error I get is `cannot convert ‘float*’ to ‘std::conditional<false, float*, std::nullptr_t>::type’ {aka ‘std::nullptr_t}` but that doesn't make any sense, `getW()` should never be ran, the comparison between `float*` and `std::nullptr_t` should never be made...?

Comment: Anyway, you will run in trouble with `T* x = &data[0];`. copy/move constructor has to be adjusted. (and you don't even have you expected syntax as you need extra `*`).

Comment: @Jarod42 Ah?! Please elaborate

Comment: Write specializations for `D = 1,2,3,4` and let `Vec<2>` inherit from `Vec<1>` etc.

Comment: This doesn't solve your problem but you'd probably be better off using a union so that `x`, `y` behave as regular member variables without bloating the class with a bunch of pointers or references.

Comment: Properties could be emulated with nested classes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties

Comment: @Kerndog73: You will have UB with union if you access non-active member union.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah I know but it's what GLM does

Comment: @小奥利奥: I meant with code similar to `Vec1 v1; *v1.x = 42; Vec1 v2 = v1; *v1.x = 51` (as spotted, `*v1.x = 42` instead of `v1.x = 42` as `x` is pointer). with default copy constructor, you would have `v1.data == v2.data` (ok), `*v1.x == *v2.x` as `v1.x == v2.x` (`== &v1.data[0]`) (`!= &v2.data[0]`).

Comment: Why would getW() never be ran in the last attempt?

Comment: @user253751 I'd assumed that would be evaluated at run-time, it was instead ran at compile-time, evidently I was wrong and there's a major issue in my understanding of c++

Comment: @user253751 come to think of it after the fact, that wouldn't have been a very good solution if it had worked, because then faulty code would've compiled fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specialize `Vec` to add these variables. Specializing the entire `Vec` class would result in a whole lot of duplicated code so you can hoist it into a base class responsible for storing the data of a vector.

```
template<size_t D, typename T>
class VecStorage {
  T data[D];

public:
  T &operator[](const size_t i) {
    return const_cast<T &>(std::as_const(*this)[i]);
  }
  const T &operator[](const size_t i) const {
    assert(i < D);
    return data[i];
  }
};

template<typename T>
class VecStorage<2, T> {
public:
  T x, y;

  T &operator[](const size_t i) {
    return const_cast<T &>(std::as_const(*this)[i]);
  }
  const T &operator[](const size_t i) const {
    assert(i < 2);
    if (i == 0) {
      return x;
    } else {
      return y;
    }
  }
};
```

I've specialized `VecStorage` for 2 dimensions. You can add specializations for 3 and 4 dimensions. Since `VecStorage` exposes the subscript operator, `Vec` and users of `Vec` can treat it like an array.

```
template<size_t D, typename T = float>
class Vec : public VecStorage<D, T> {
public:
  explicit Vec(T initial = 0) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i != D; ++i) {
      (*this)[i] = initial;
    }
  }
};

int main() {
  Vec<2> v{42};
  std::cout << v.x << ' ' << v.y << '\n'; // 42 42
  v[0] = 5;
  v[1] = 7;
  std::cout << v.x << ' ' << v.y << '\n'; // 5 7
}
```

Comment: I was in the process of implementing this after you made your comment, thanks. I had originally set `D` to be of type `size_t` because I believe I've seen that done somewhere else, but changed it to `int` afterwards because I don't know the significance of it. Care to tell me?

Comment: You should use the largest possible integer type for template parameters because there's no reason not to. There's no need to worry about it taking up too much space or anything like that. If you look at the standard library, `std::array` uses `size_t` for the size of the array.