# How can i make allow all instances of a class access 1 array? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, oop

I am trying to make two classes: the class 1 generates an array which is same for all instances of class 2. How can i allow access to the array i generated for all classes? I know i could just pass them as parameters, but maybe there is a better way?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: The `static` modifier?

Answer (score 0):

Class 2 could just use static, but I consider the static keyword *semantic waste*, because static class fields cannot be readily identified at a glance in code. Semantic waste is basically any programming language feature outside the scope of what a language should do.

Just bind each instance to a reference to the data.

My architecture is all about sharing access to data across code bodies via *reference properties*. I don't have a C++ implementation ready, but you can find a C++ implementation for properties here [Does C++11 have C#-style properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties) and my architecture in C# at http://www.powersemantics.com/