# How to "properly" translate C# properties to C++?

Tags: c#, c++

I have written a chart library in C#. I'm writing the exact same library, but for C++, as a learning project. The main issue I'm having right now is translating all of the C# properties to C++. Originally, I was planning on just writing out all the getters and setters as functions but, because of the way my library is structured, it makes the code a bit hard to read. Let me explain with an example:

If I wanted to change the minimum value of the X Axis for the first subplot, I'd do something like this in C#:

```
myChart.Subplots[0].Axes.X.Bounds.Min = 5;
```

In C++, the same code would look like this:

```
myChart.GetSubplot(0).GetAxes().GetXAxis().GetBounds().SetMin(5);
```

Maybe I'm too used to C#, but this just looks very wrong to me. In the C# version you can just glance over the code and immediately see what's going on, whereas the C++ one is really long and convoluted. Initially I thought about just making everything public, but not only is this a bad idea, but I'd also like to make some of the getters and setters private.

What should I do? Should I stick to what I'm doing currently? Should I completely restructure my library to be more "C++"-like? Is there an alternative method that I'm unaware of?

Comment: you can get `myChart.Subplots[0].Axes.X.Bounds.Min = 5;` in C++ as well, but you will have to either play some tricks that require lots of boilerplate, or sacrifice encapsulation. Why does it look very wrong to you? Thats rather subjective

Comment: Why would the C++ code look like you've shown in the question? If you want it to look like the C# code, you can make it look like that. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/j4GjjTKrY)

Comment: fwiw, prefixing getters with `Get` is a convention you do not need to follow ( I personally find it stupid and only use it when I really cannot give it a better meaningful name). Would you complain as well about `myChart.Subplot(0).Axes().XAxis().Bounds().Min() = 5;` ?

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 The example without the "Get" prefix looks much nicer, I'll probably end up just doing that, thanks. To answer your original comment: It looks bad to me because 60% of the code is just "Get" and "()" instead of meaningful information.

Comment: @LogDog What stops you from using exactly the same syntax as in C# like I showed in my example?

Comment: This question is getting downvoted because it is opinion based. If you don't want to be downvoted, ask a better question. [https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: There are some hacks here, but nothing very appealing really: [Does C++11 have C#-style properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8368512/does-c11-have-c-style-properties)

Comment: You might get more help at [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/?tags=c%23)

Comment: @NicholasHunter Generic best practices are not not on-topic on Code Review.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I might be misinterpreting the code you gave me, but as far as I can see you just made everything a public struct? Sometimes I don't want to give the user the ability to set something, like the Axes property for example. Also, most of the time I want to implement additional logic when setting a field, such as updating other chart components or raising events.

Comment: Yes, that was to make it all public. If you need additional logic, I suggest sticking with plain functions, returning references or `const&`. You can use proxy objects (like in the post @NicholasHunter linked to) but that makes it even more messy and hard to read (i.m.o.).