# Accessing fields and methods of custom properties in C++

Tags: c++, properties

This is a followup on [a question on how to have C#-like properties in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8368512/3358488).

A [representative answer of that thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478633/3358488) suggests using:

```
template <typename T>
class Property {
public:
    virtual ~Property() {}  //C++11: use override and =default;
    virtual T& operator= (const T& f) { return value = f; }
    virtual const T& operator() () const { return value; }
    virtual explicit operator const T& () const { return value; }
    virtual T* operator->() { return &value; }
protected:
    T value;
};
```

The advantage of doing something like that is that `Property` methods can be overridden in derived classes to add behavior to the field. For example, I may override the assignment method to log an event in a logger:

```
virtual T& operator= (const T& f) { 
    logger.log(string("Assigning ") + f + " to property");
    return value = f;
}
```

while maintaining the access to the property as if it were a field:

```
struct Building {
    Property<float> height;
};
Building a;
a.height = 10; // runs code (logging the event) even though it is accessed like a field.
```

However this does not work if you want to access a field or method of the property value as in:

```
struct Shape {
    double area() const {
        return 10;
    }
};

struct Drawing {
    Property<Shape> shape;
};

int main() {
    Drawing d;
    return d.shape.area(); // error: Property<Shape> does not have method 'area'
}
```

Is there a way to overcome this limitation without modifying the client code using the class?

The purpose of the question is that I am refactoring legacy code that accesses public fields and trying to replace those fields by a property so that I can improve the implementation of the behavior associated with that field without changing the way the client code accesses it.

Comment: What would `d.shape->area()` do ?

Comment: Or maybe `d.shape().area()` even.

Comment: Honestly, I don't think you gain *anything* by that, compared to ordinary variables as long as your properties allow modifications of the values anyway (public assignment!). If at all that might be interesting for public read and private write access. In that case you might make the parent a friend of the property, thus an additional template parameter.

Comment: @Jeffrey as mentioned at the end of the question, changing shape to be a pointer or function won't work because I am working with legacy code that accesses `shade` as a field.

Comment: @Aconcagua: I've added some more to the text to illustrate why one may want to implement this.

Comment: Hm. even if your property class worked your overall code wouldn't – you return const references, but `area` function is non-const, so couldn't be called on anyway. Maybe just an error in the example, but such effects need to be kept in mind as well...

Comment: True, thanks. `area` should be const, I've updated that.