# Can I merge virtual pointer of data members with virtual pointer of containing class to save space?

Tags: c++, oop

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478633) I learnt how to make properties in c++, which have virtual function member to override in derived classes, but my question is: Let's say we have a class like this

```
class Point{
  public:
    Property<float> x;
    Property<float> y;
    virtual void Move();
};
```

This class has two properties, each one is an object with virtual functions and a virtual pointer. The `Point` class also has a virtual table and a pointer. Now can I have only one virtual pointer for the containing class `Point` and all its data members to save space?

Comment: How virtual functions are implemented is implementation-specific. And also I highly doubt you would save any significant amount of space if you could do what you are trying to do, this feels like a case of premature optimization

Comment: No. And also, I don't see any point whatsoever of faking a property.

Comment: Where exactly do you want to "save space"? Since ```Property``` is instantiated directly as a member (and not as a pointer), there is no vtable access required for it. Additionally, vtables are globals so they only get created once in the entire program (and not once per object).

Comment: @UnholySheep If millions of object are going to be created it would save significant amount of space.

Comment: As I had commented in the linked answer, there's probably no reason to use `virtual` for the Property template class, since there's **no** *polymorphism* happening.

Answer (score 1):

The vtable is a per-class thing, fields are a per-instance thing. So "moving the fields to the vtable" doesn't make sense. If you want to group the vptr and the fields in a structure on the heap and only have a pointer inside `Point`, then it sounds like what you have in mind is a `Point*`.

It won't save space - there was no space wasted to begin with.