# How do I simulate C#'s {get; set;} in C++?

Tags: c++

I am experimenting with lambda functions and managed to recreate a "get" functionality in C++. I can get the return value of a function without using parentheses. This is an example class, where I implement this:

```
using namespace std;

struct Vector2 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float length = [&]()-> float {return sqrt(x * x + y * y); }();
    float angle = [&]()-> float {return atan2(y, x); }();

    Vector2() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Vector2(float a, float b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    ~Vector2() {}
    Vector2(Vector2& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}
    Vector2(Vector2&& other) = delete;
    void operator =(Vector2&& other) noexcept{
        x = other.x;
        y = other.y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector2 vec = Vector2(10, 17);
    printf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n", vec.x, vec.y, vec.length, vec.angle);
}
```

However, I am currently trying to also recreate the "set" functionality that C# has. But I'm failing. I tried to add this:

```
void angle = [&](float a)->void {
    float l = length;
    x = cos(a) * l;
    y = sin(a) * l;
};
```

But am getting "Incomplete type is not allowed" error. I'm not sure if that's how it should look, even if I wasn't getting the error. Is it even possible to recreate the "set" functionality C# has in C++?

I know that I can just use a method `SetAngle(float a){...}`, but that's not really the point.

Comment: The specific problem is in `void angle`, because a lambda isn't of type void. Try `auto angle` instead.

Comment: Now I'm getting error E1598 - 'auto' is not allowed here.

Comment: Ok, you cannot have `auto` members.

Comment: Also, if you test some more, you will find that `float angle = [&]()-> float {return atan2(y, x); }();` isn't actually a getter, but a plain member variable. The lambda is excuted once as an initializaton, not each time the member  is accessed.

Comment: Hmm, curious.. I indeed hadn't noticed that... Is there a way to make it work like an actual getter?
(The way this currently works can actually be used to create "constant" (instance specific) variables, which can be initialized, but can't be changed later)

Comment: It can be done by overriding implicit cast and assignment operator: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/5283099/CSharpish-Properties-in-Modern-Cplusplus

Comment: Depending on your requirements for language purity, Visual C++ has a "property" extension that does this.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/property-cpp?view=msvc-170

Comment: You are on the wrong path. You can achieve what you want with a proxy object: defining implicit conversion for get and equal operator for set. Implementing it without undue overhead (meaning without storing the this pointer) is non trivial. IIRC it is achivable with some usage of offsetof assuming your class has standard memory layout. IMO not worth the trouble except as an exercise.

Comment: @TimRoberts your solution worked perfectly! Can you post it as an answer, so I can mark it as a solution?
I am going to sleep, however, so will mark it tomorrow.

Comment: C# `get` & `set` are just syntactic sugar for member functions.  C++ does not have that syntactic sugar.  [C# like class properties](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7786/c-like-class-properties)  by thesaint, and [mimic properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478633/4641116) by Michael Litvin are interesting experiments, but I would not recommend using those techniques in non-toy C++ code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While other solutions also seem to be possible, this one seems to be the most elegant :P

```
using namespace std;

struct Vector2 {
    float x;
    float y;
    float init_length = [&]()-> float {return sqrt(x * x + y * y); }();
    float init_angle = [&]()-> float {return atan2(y, x); }();

    __declspec(property(get = GetAngle, put = SetAngle)) float angle;
    __declspec(property(get = GetLength, put = SetLength)) float length;


    Vector2() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Vector2(float a, float b) : x(a), y(b) {}
    ~Vector2() {}
    Vector2(Vector2& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}
    Vector2(Vector2&& other) = delete;
    void operator =(Vector2&& other) = delete;

    void Display() {
        printf("%f\n%f\n%f\n%f\n\n", x, y, length, angle);
    }

    float GetLength() {
        return sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    float GetAngle() {
        return atan2(y, x);
    }

    void SetLength(float l) {
        float a = GetAngle();
        x = cos(a) * l;
        y = sin(a) * l;
    }

    void SetAngle(float a) {
        float l = GetLength();
        x = cos(a) * l;
        y = sin(a) * l;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Vector2 vec = Vector2(10, 17);
    vec.Display();
    vec.length = 5;
    vec.Display();
}
```

Comment: But how portable is it?

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR: Don't**

What you have isn't a getter, it's just a normal data member that's calculated once when the object is initialized.

In general, C++ doesn't support C#-style properties.  The usual C++-style solution is to just use a pair of member functions (and maybe a data member, if you need to save the value separately), i.e.

```
struct Vector2 {
    // ...

    float length() const { return sqrt(x * x + y * y); }
    void length(float l) {
        float angle = angle();
        float new_x = l * cos(angle);
        float new_y = l * sin(angle);
        x = new_x;
        y = new_y;
    }

    // ...
};
```

---

You can get something close to a C#-style property, but you'll always run into edge-cases where they don't work perfectly.  For example, here's something that will work in many cases:

```
template <typename T>
class Property
{
private:
    std::function<T()> getter_;
    std::function<void(const T&)> setter_;

public:
    Property(std::function<T()> getter, std::function<void(const T&)> setter)
        : getter_{getter},
          setter_{setter}
    {}

    operator T()
    {
        return getter_();
    }

    const T& operator=(const T& val)
    {
        setter_(val);
        return val;
    }
};

struct Vector2
{
    float x;
    float y;
    Property<float> length{
        [this]() { return sqrt(x * x + y * y); },
        [this](float l) {
            float new_x = l * cos(angle);
            float new_y = l * sin(angle);
            x = new_x;
            y = new_y;
        }
    }

    Property<float> angle{
        [this]() { return atan2(y, x); },
        [this](float a) {
            float l = length;
            x = cos(a) * l;
            y = sin(a) * l;
        }
    }

    // ...
};

int main() {
    Vector2 v;
    v.x = 1;
    v.y = 1;

    v.angle = std::numbers::pi / 2;
    std::cout << "(" << v.x << ", " << v.y << ")\n";
}
```

But this still falls apart in the edge cases, especially when you mix it with templates and/or `auto` type-deduction.  For instance:

```
Vector2 v;
v.x = 1;
v.y = 1;

auto old_angle = v.angle;
v.angle = std::numbers::pi / 2;

// oops, this prints pi/2, not pi/4 like you probably expected
// because old_angle isn't a float, it's a Property<float> that
// references v
std::cout << old_angle << '\n';
```

Note also that there's a bug here.  Consider this:

```
int main() {
    Vector2 v1;
    v1.x = 1;
    v1.y = 1;

    Vector2 v2 = v1;
    v2.angle = std::numbers::pi / 2;

    // Oops, assigning to v2.angle modified v1
    std::cout << "(" << v1.x << ", " << v1.y << ")\n";
}
```

You could work around these issues by making `Property` non-copyable, but then you force any class that uses it to implement a custom copy-constructor.  Also, while that would make the `auto` case "safe", it does so by turning it into a compile error.  Still not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Miles. This is not the greatest idea, because it's unnatural for C++ developers, and you should write code that is first and foremost easy to read.

However, as an engineering challenge, here's a possible implementation:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
class Member
{
public:
    operator T() const { return _value; }
    void operator =(const T& value) const { _value = value; }                                                                                                                                                             void operator =(T&& value) { _value = std::move(value); }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                      private:
    T _value;
};

class Angle
{
public:
    Angle(const Member<float>& x, const Member<float>& y) :
        _x(x), _y(y) {}

    operator float() const { return atan2(_y, _x); }

private:
    const Member<float>& _x, _y;
};

class Obj
{
public:
    Member<float> x, y;
    Angle angle;

    Obj() : angle(this->x, this->y) {}
};

int main()
{
    Obj o;
    o.x = 3;
    o.y = 5;
    std::cout << o.x << ", " << o.y << " -> " << o.angle << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this really covers OP's use-case.  It looks to me like they want, i.e. `v.angle = pi / 2` to modify `v.x` and `v.y` rather than just updating a separate `angle` member.

Comment: You are right @MilesBudnek, I took a shortcut and didn't give a full example. Thanks for pointing that out. Here is a better solution.