# Why is the return value incorrect with optimisation flags on?

Tags: c++

I am (for myself only) practicing c++ and trying to "re-code" c# properties into it.
***I do know it is useless*** (I mean, I will not use it) however, I just wanted to try to see if this was possible.

For some reasons, with the following code, under the latest clang / gcc version, it does not yeld the correct result under every single optimisation flags other than `-O0` (which disables optimisation as far as I am aware of.)

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
class Property
{
private:
    using getType = std::function<const T&(void)>;
    using setType = std::function<void(const T&)>;

    T internal;

    getType get;
    setType set;
public:
    Property(const T &value) : internal{value}, get{[this] () { return internal; }}, set{[this](const T& value) { internal = value; }} {}
    Property(getType fnc) : get(fnc) {  }
    Property(getType fncGet, setType fncSet) : get(fncGet), set(fncSet) {  }

    Property(setType fnc) : set(fnc) {  }
    Property(setType fncSet, getType fncGet) : get(fncGet), set(fncSet) {  }

    Property<T> &operator=(T& value) { set(value); return *this; }

    operator const T&() const { return get(); }
};

int main(void)
{
    Property<int> hey(12);

    std::cout << hey << std::endl;

    return hey;
}
```

It seems to behave correctly under visual studio compiler but i'm unsure.

Have I missed a part of the standard? Is my code incorrect? is there a bug in clang / gcc / the STL?

I placed my code on the website called Godbolt to switch easily between compilers and I had the same incoherent results.

Here is what it prints me for c++14 / clang 14:

```
ASM generation compiler returned: 0
Execution build compiler returned: 0
Program returned: 0
624203080
```

*The last number changes between runs, but not the first one making me think it just takes uninitialized data.*

Comment: Try casting `hey` to `int`. The `main` function should only return an `int`.

Comment: The `[this]` capture in the constructor is iffy: after moving or copying a `Property<T>` using the default copy/move constructors, it will still refer to the original. My bet is on this causing a dangling reference somewhere that you then use.

Comment: Michael Litvin had an interesting approach to C# style [properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35478633/4641116) in C++.

Comment: @Eljay indeed however from what I read, it is based on inheritance which I did not want mine to be :) but thanks for pointing out! I will definitely read in details what he wrote!

Comment: My comment to Michael's post was that there was no reason (or benefit) for `virtual` in his implementation, since there is no polymorphism.  But I concede that non-polymorphic inheritance is still inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is this part: `using getType = std::function<const T&(void)>;` in combination with `get{[this] () { return internal; }}`.

The lambda does not return the `internal` as a reference here, so a copy of `internal` is returned, and - here I don't know how `std::function` is implemented - `std::function` has to hold a copy of `internal` but returns it as a reference to that copy which is than dangling.

Changing it to `get{[this] () -> T& { return internal; }}` seems to solve the problem.

Comment: wow I really did think std function would "force" the lambda to return a value by reference, since its signature is a reference return...

Comment: @AzKalaak nope, C++ closure objects are entirely determined from the lambda expression

Answer (score 3):

The lambda you initialise `get` with returns by value, not by reference, which means that the returned `int` ceases to exist somewhere in the `std::function` machinery.

You can specify a reference return

```
[this] () -> const T& { return internal; }
```

N.b. you should make `Property` uncopyable and immovable, as you can't re-point the `this` capture within the `std::function` members when copying or moving.