# Possible to convert C# get,set code to C++

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I have the following code in C#:

```
public string Temp
        {
            get { return sTemp; }
            set { 
                sTemp = value;
                this.ComputeTemp();
            }
        }
```

Is it possible to convert this and use the get and set this way? I know that you cannot declare like so and I need the ":" to declare but when I try to do this:

```
public:
        std::string Temp
        {
        get { return sTemp; }
        set { 
                sTemp = value;
                this.ComputeTemp();
            }
```

The error I receive is on the first "{" stating `expected a ';'`. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

Comment: **Moderator Note:** This question has already run its course.  If you want to comment on its veracity, take it to the [meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191089/why-do-we-let-hostile-users-dictate-the-perception-of-stack-overflow).  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C#-like properties in native C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225087/c-like-properties-in-native-c)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Are you using C++/CLI?  If so this is the property syntax

```
public:
  property std::string Temp { 
    std::string get() { return sTemp; }
    void set(std::string value) { sTemp = value; this->ComputeTemp(); } 
  }
```

If you are trying to use normal C++ then you are out of luck.  There is no equivalent feature for normal C++ code.  You will need to resort to getter and setter methods

```
public:
  std::string GetTemp() const { return sTemp; } 
  void SetTemp(const std::string& value) { 
    sTemp = value;
    this->ComputeTemp();
  }
```

Comment: In the latter case, the standard naming convention seems to be `T temp()` for the getter and `void temp(T value)` for the setter.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I've definitely seen both ways (Get / Set prefix and no prefix). My personal preference is to have the Get / Set prefix, possibly a hold over from my early Java days

Answer (score 11):

To copy paste one of my answers from a similar question:

**WARNING: This is a tongue-in-cheek response and is terrible!!!**

Yes, it's sort of possible :)

```
template<typename T>
class Property
{
private:
    T& _value;

public:
    Property(T& value) : _value(value)
    {
    }   // eo ctor

    Property<T>& operator = (const T& val)
    {
        _value = val;
        return(*this);
    };  // eo -

    operator const T&() const
    {
        return(_value);
    };  // eo ()
};
```

Then declare your class, declaring properties for your members:

```
class Test
{
private:
    std::string m_Test;

public:
    Test() : text(m_Test)
    {
    };

    Property<std::string> text;
};
```

And call C# style!

```
Test a;
a.text = "blah";

std::string content = a.text;
```

Comment: Note that Properties in this manner make the class a little larger than they'd otherwise be

Comment: @MooingDuck, correct - but I'd also advise doing it in the first place, hence the disclaimer at the top - point being - it *can* be done...  just..  yeah... ;)

Comment: Copy construction of `Test` and `Test::operator=` are disastrous.  You need to either handle it properly, or block it.

Comment: Oh, and you can get rid of the overhead, *and* have a working `operator=`, by simply giving up on `.` syntax.  Use `static TestProperty text;` to introduce a name into the global scope with suitable overrides to `operator^` and you can get `a^text = "blah"` to work to work, with zero run time overhead.  To add to the C#ness, `Test* a; a^text` and `Test a; a^text` can both do the same thing: why store the `Test` object when the statement *has it right there*, all we need to do is some expression template mojo to grab it and use it!

Answer (score 3):

In Visual C++ you can use `__declspec(property)`, like this:

```
public:
    __declspec(property(get=get_Temp, put=set_Temp)) std::string Temp;

    const std::string& get_Temp { return sTemp; }
    void set_Temp(std::string value) { 
            sTemp = std::move(value);
            this->ComputeTemp();
    }
```

Comment: However, it's better to just use `get_Temp/set_Temp` directly, without the property `Temp`, because it's way easier to grep places where Temp is accessed/modified.